Azure Database for MySQL replication using GTID's
I have been testing the Azure Database for MySQL. I need to set up a replica in Azure with the Source database being on prem here.
So far I have got a basic replica set up and running, but I need it to replicate using GTID's. Looking at the documentation I can see that I need to run:
az mysql flexible-server gtid reset
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/flexible-server/gtid?view=azure-cli-latest
What I can't figure out is where I need to run this command, as it's clearly not an SQL command, and (as far as I can tell) I don't have access to the underlying VM to run a commandline on the VM.
So where does this command go?

This commands is for Azure CLI, meaning you need to access the console for Azure to execute this command.
